# How can I use a variable declared in a while loop outside the while loop?

Tags: c++

```
#include"std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
 int i = 0;
 int x = i + 2;
 while(i<10){
  ++i;
 }
 cout<<x<<'\n';
}
```

I am a beginner and I want the result to print: after every loop i should get incremented by 1 which it does but the problem is if we print x it is still 2. Please provide an answer.

Comment: `x` is a copy of `i + 2`. Do you want it to be a reference to `i`? Why not just print `i`?

Comment: I'm confused.  Your code never changes `x`, so why would you expect it to change?

Comment: I'm guessing you want your `x` too increase by `i + 2` too after every iteration? Why not put it in the loop too?

Comment: Stephen so how can I change x by adding i and 2 in it....

Comment: You should try to better understand or better explain what you're actually trying to achieve. Your original code is written as if the value of a variable is evaluated when it is printed, rather than when it is assigned.

Comment: Please include the exact output you *want* to see from your code (don't describe it, actually write what number(s) you want to see and in what order along with any line breaks) so we can better understand what changes you need to make.

Comment: In C++ you cannot set up a formula ahead of time and have it recompute when the variables involved are changed. Every time you want a formula recomputed you must recompute it. `x`'s value is set at `int x = i + 2;` and will not be changed unless you explicitly assign to `x`  later in the code (or have a programming mistake that writes to an incorrect location in memory. Try to avoid that as it can be very tricky to debug).

Comment: Hey thanks...I didn't know about that....it helped me a lot bro....

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `i` is already incremented but but the problem was, the `x` is **already** assigned previously by 0 + 2 (i + 2) and loop executed later, therefore the value was unchanged. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int x;

    for (; i < 10; i++) // same algorithm as per of your requirement in FOR loop
    {
        x = i + 2;
        std::cout << x << std::endl; // x will be incremented each time
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No problem, you can mark it as correct answer then ^_^